# python create 25 separate arrays with ranges [0,0,0] to [1,0,0]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to make a np.array that creates a 25x3 array gradually building up each time. Starting from [0,0,0] and ending with [1,0,0].

The purpose is making a color parameter NumPy (n,3) array, where n(25) is the number of data points and each of the three columns corresponds to an RGB value in the range [0,1]

Example:
array([[0,0,0],
...
...
...
...
[1,0,0]])

I've gotten close but am having trouble with decimals.

What I've tried:
array = np.array([[i for i in range(3)] for j in range(25)])

array = np.linespace(0,1,25) # this was close but wasn't the right format.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are looking for  `np.linspace((0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), 25)`

This works because we can pass in "array_like" objects in for start and stop if we like.

Comment: thank you , I believe this worked for what i need !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly.

If you need a list of lists starting from [0 0 0] and ending with [1 0 0], I assume the first entry is the one varying (in this example).

If that is the case, you could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Start from [0 0 0] and end with [1 0 0]

n = 25 # Number of points in your array
l = []

for i in range(n):
    l.append([i/(n-1), 0, 0])

l = np.array(l)

print(l)
```

Comment: This worked and produced the same result as Cameron(above), Cool to see it in different ways. Cheers!